# Is the axial gauge with a $\xi$ term useful in Yang-Mills theory?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, gauge

i) Do people use axial gauge with a $\xi$ term? When $\xi\neq 0$, ghosts do not decouple, but maybe it's still useful?

ii) Is it proved that the term $\frac 1 {2\xi}(n.A)^2$ in the Lagrangian does not renormalize, for $\xi=0$ and $\xi\neq 0$?

Comment: There is no problem with this gauge: you are specifying one component of A to be a fixed random variable. I don't know if people use it.